# jaxb transformerfactory xml to xml via xslt using generate-id for unique values

Tags: xslt, jaxb

I have the following bit of code to transform one xml document into another via xslt

```
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ie.getXslFileName())));
        transformer.transform(
                new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader),
                new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(stream));
        output.put(fileName, stream.toByteArray());
```

It works perfectly if I do not attempt to select disctinct values.  However, as soon as I put in the generate-id line and key it fails.  In every other test tool I use the transformation is perfect so I am thinking it is a limitation in jaxb's transformer?  Does anyone have any suggestion as to how I can select unique values that will work here AND enable jaxb transformation?  OR, alternatively, is there another transformer I could use that would do the trick?

XSLT that works everywhere BUT here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:key name="groupKey"
           match="//questionGroup/externalCodes/externalCode/externalCode/text()" 
           use="." />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="submissionReport"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="submissionReport" >
    <component>
      <structuredBody>
        <xsl:for-each select="//questionResponse/question/questionGroup
                               /externalCodes/externalCode[governingBody
                                [internalCode='GVB-AHRQ-1']]
                               /externalCode/text()[generate-id() = 
                                  generate-id(key('groupKey',.)[1])]">
          <component>
            <section>
              <entry>
                <templateId>
                  <xsl:attribute name="root">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                </templateId>
                <organizer classCode="CLUSTER" moodCode="EVN">
                  <id nullFlavor="NA"/>
                  <statusCode code="completed"/>
                  <xsl:call-template name="groupedResponses">
                    <xsl:with-param name="groupInternalCode" select="."/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </organizer>
              </entry>
            </section>
          </component>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </structuredBody>
    </component>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="groupedResponses">
    <xsl:param name="groupInternalCode"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//questionResponse[question[externalCodes
                            [externalCode[governingBody[internalCode='GVB-AHRQ-1'] and 
                               not(externalCode='DE42') and not(externaCode='DE3') and 
                               not(externalCode='DE46') and not(externalCode='DE49') and 
                               not(externalCode='DE30')]] and 
                               questionGroup[externalCodes[externalCode[governingBody[internalCode='GVB-AHRQ-1'] and 
                               externalCode=$groupInternalCode]]]]]">
      <component>
        <observation>
          <xsl:attribute name="classCode">OBS</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="moodCode">EVN</xsl:attribute>
          <templateId>
            <xsl:attribute name="root">2.16.840.1.113883.3.263.1.11.3.100</xsl:attribute>
          </templateId>
          <xsl:for-each select="question/externalCodes/externalCode
                                   [governingBody[internalCode='GVB-AHRQ-1'] or 
                                   governingBody[internalCode='GVB-CDCRACE-1'] or 
                                   governingBody[internalCode='GVB-HL7NULL-1'] or 
                                   governingBody[internalCode='GVB-HL7GENDER-1']]">
            <!-- Question information -->
            <code>
              <xsl:attribute name="code">
                <xsl:value-of select="externalCode"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="displayName">
                <xsl:value-of select="../../text"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="codeSystem">
                <xsl:value-of select="governingBody/externalCode"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="codeSystemName">
                <xsl:value-of select="governingBody/name"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </code>

            <!-- Response information.  Can be more than one -->
            <xsl:for-each select="../../../response">
              <value>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="responseOption">
                    <xsl:for-each select="responseOption/externalCodes/externalCode">
                      <value>
                        <xsl:attribute name="type">CD</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="code">
                          <xsl:value-of select="externalCode"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="displayName">
                          <xsl:value-of select="../../response"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="codeSystem">
                          <xsl:value-of select="governingBody/externalCode"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="codeSystemName">
                          <xsl:value-of select="governingBody/name"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                      </value>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:when>

                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <value>
                      <xsl:attribute name="type">ED</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:attribute name="mediaType">text/plain</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="response"/>
                    </value>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </value>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </observation>
      </component>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "it fails" - in what way?  Do you get an error message, no output at all, different output from what you expect....?

Comment: In case `generate-id()` is the issue, you could try the other Muenchian grouping formula: `path/field[count(. | key('groupKey', .)[1]) = 1]`

Comment: @Ian - no error message but no data is returned.  The entire section marked for this returns <structureBody/> where in any other parser environment it returns all sorts of data there with the same source and xslt.

Comment: What does the source XML look like? Why are you using Muenchian grouping in the first place if you're using XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Muenchian grouping will not necessarily work if you have a predicate mid-path the way you do there. You should put the predicate between the `key()` and the `[1]`, or in the key definition.

Comment: @JLRishe - You are correct, I still have 2.0 indicated there though I have given up on 2.0.  I was attempting to use the distinc-values() call and it failed as well.  I just forgot to return the indication when I posted this.  Can you give me a line of code to show what you mean by "put the predicate between the key()..."

Comment: I think the typical way to do grouping in XSLT 2.0 is to use `xsl:for-each-group`. What I meant by the statement you quoted was something like this: `//questionResponse/question/questionGroup/externalCodes/externalCode/externalCode[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groupKey',.)[../../governingBody/internalCode = 'GHB-AHRQ-1'][1])]`

Comment: Sadly putting the predicate there did not help.  I am further along than I was but still not there.  I have set the key now to be `<xsl:key name="groupKey" match="//questionResponse/question/questionGroup/externalCodes/externalCode/externalCode/text()" use="." />` and the selection to be `<xsl:for-each select="//questionResponse/question/questionGroup/externalCodes/externalCode[governingBody[internalCode='GVB-AHRQ-1']]/externalCode/text()[count(.|key('groupKey',.)[1]) = 1]">`.  It is returning values but not limiting to the unique instances.  The keys are repeated.  More missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26494/discussion-between-eva-donaldson-and-jlrishe)

Comment: Can you add an example of the input XML to your question, as I already requested?

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help.  I decided to go with importing Saxon to enable XSLT 2.0.  Seconds later grouping is perfect and works easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I decided to go with importing Saxon to enable XSLT 2.0. Seconds later grouping is perfect and works easily.